# How to send and recive a QUERY parameters with HTTP request

Tags: java, mysql, spring, http, httprequest

I've try to send a query parameters with http request but I don't know how to do that, here is my actual controler

```
package com.iquest.news.controller;

import com.iquest.news.dao.AbstractGenericDao;
import com.iquest.news.entities.News;
import com.iquest.news.services.ServiceInterface;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class NewsController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceInterface<News> newsService;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractGenericDao.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showNews(Model model) {
        List<News> news = newsService.getAll();
        if (news.size() != 0) {
            model.addAttribute("news", news);
            logger.debug("CONTROLLER: News controller has executed with success");
            return "news";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/startDate={date}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNewsByDate(@PathVariable long date, Model model) {
        List<News> news = newsService.getNewsByDate(date);
        if (news.size() != 0) {
            model.addAttribute("news", news);
            logger.debug("CONTROLLER: News controller has delivered data (from GET NEWS BY DATE) with success");
            return "news";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/startDate={date}/author={author}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNewsByDateAndAuthor(@PathVariable long date, @PathVariable String author, Model model) {
        List<News> news = newsService.getNewsByDateAndAuthor(date, author);
        if (news.size() != 0) {
            model.addAttribute("news", news);
            logger.debug("CONTROLLER: News controller has delivered data (from GET NEWS BY DATE AND AUTHOR) with success");
            return "news";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

And here it's my URL link after executed that: http://localhost:8080/news/startDate=1436529204/author=v

How I can make this URL to look like: http://localhost:8080/news?startDate=1436529204?author=v or something like that.
Have anyone any idea how I can do that? 
Thx for help :D

Comment: have a look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: You actually have to bind Request Parameters but not Path Parameters. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a way to do this.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/news"},method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST,
            org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET})
    public String getQueryParams(final Model model,final HttpServletRequest request){
String startDate= request.getParameter("startDate");
String author= request.getParameter("author");
}
```

Comment: If I used that method, http://i.imgur.com/ikskAta.png and with this link: localhost:8080/news?startDate=1436531644&author=v he change me automatic in this http://localhost:8080/news/?startDate=1436531644&author=v and I don't know why, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Actualy "URL" with more than one question mark ("?") is not a valid URL. If you are looking how to access query parameters of a valid URL like  http://localhost:8080/news?startDate=1436529204&author=v then your method signature should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getNewsByDateAndAuthor(@RequestParam("date") Long date, @RequestParam("author") String author, Model model) {
```

Comment: If I used that, http://i.imgur.com/7IZRZeB.png and try to used that link localhost:8080/news?startDate=1436531644&author=v here is my result, and I don't know why didn't work: http://i.imgur.com/h7seoc5.png every time when I use this link he change automatic in this http://localhost:8080/news/?startDate=1436531644&author=v did you know what I can do?

Comment: I believe your dispatcher servlet mapping has a problem can you please share the same. You can see the same in error on console "No mapping found".